# How to run animation only on first page visit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

on the sveltekit website I'm currently building I want to play a simple intro animation on the index page if it is the entrypoint to the app. If a user used the navigation to load the index page the animation should not play.

So i'm looking for a simple way to detect if a page is the entrypoint from that session or not.

Here is an example page with such functionality reed.be/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [SvelteKit's `afterNavigate`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation) to detect where the current navigation came from. Only animate if it's not coming from another page on the same domain. Here is what the index page could look like:

```html
<script>
    import { afterNavigate } from '$app/navigation';
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition';

    // hide by default
    let visible = false;

    let duration;

    afterNavigate(({ from }) => {
        // only animate if the navigation came from outside the page
        duration = from === null ? 600 : 0;
        // toggle visbility in any case
        visible = true;
    });
</script>

{#if visible}
    <h1 in:fade={{ duration }}>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the snippet, thats exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to use `in:` with a custom transition. Since there are no ways (that I know of) to enable or disable a transition conditionally on an element, you could send a custom parameter to the transition function that indicates if it is the first load or not, and if it is you can enable or disable (i.e. set duration to 0 or something like that) the transition in the transition code itself. The first load variable could be a global store.

Not recommended but another way I see is to have two if blocks on the first load variable so you have two sets of the dom code but one is without the `in:` transition.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas, ich think i will create a custom transition function with an enable/disable parameter